# Android Application with web services implementation

Tags: android, database, web-services

I am new to Android Platform and want to create one Application in which the data should be fetched using web services implementation.Like **OLX** Application in which the Application is installed on Android phone and data is fetched from web service which web services can also used while creating Web site for same client.

Need Some Reference or if someone can provide demo project that will be helpful.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a WebView. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: No No i dont want to open web page, but i want to lode data from data base which is on remote computer via web service into android application

Answer (score 0):

You should use httpget to fetch a json from an online webservice then parse the JSON and display it on the application. note that you should use an intent service or asynctask as you can do any networking on the main thread.

I can't provide you right now with a sample code but I might be able by tomorrow night.
If you want you can check this link (but they are using Android Studio) http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/

Comment: i also want to learn how to create web service according to our need and where to host it with database,So i can create that live project for my semester project.if you can provide those information and sample code that will be very grateful.

Comment: What server side programming language are you using?

Comment: i know bit of PHP, .NET, Java so i can create on any of them ,i don't know which one will appropriate for this.

Comment: @newCode the code on the server doesn't matter. you can create a json web service using any of those languages. you are mainly asking for a whole project :) I don't think

Comment: i don't need whole project i want to create and learn that but i need reference so i can complete it fast. :)

Comment: Sorry @newCode but I might be able to provide with a sample android  application. if you need help with how to create a webservice please ask another question or google how to create a json restful webservice.

Comment: Ok.. Thank you.. :) if you got the free time and its posible to send code then plz provide it.. else i will manage